# UIView doesn't animate horizontally from right to left

Tags: ios, swift

I have two `UIButtons` inside an horizontal `UIStackView`. I want to add a `UIView` as a subview so that when I press one of the buttons, the view moves horizontally to the selected button.

I have this code:

```
let selectionView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 19))
selectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
self.incomeButton.addSubview(selectionView) // left button


// left button touched
@IBAction func incomeDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.incomeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    self.expensiveButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.grayColor(), forState: .Normal)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
        self.selectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        self.selectionView.center = self.incomeButton.center
    }
}

// right button touched   
@IBAction func expensiveDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.expensiveButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    self.incomeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.grayColor(), forState: .Normal)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
        self.selectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.selectionView.center = self.expensiveButton.center
    }
```

This code actually works when the view is added to the left button. The view will move from left to right and right to left when clicking the buttons.

But if I start with the right button selected:

```
    let selectionView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 19))
    selectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.expensiveButton.addSubview(selectionView)  // right button
```

The view only changes the color, but doesn't move from right to left.

Why is that ? How can I fix my code so that the view can be moved either way ?

`UPDATE`:

I tried adding the stack view inside an `UIView` and also add the selectionView inside it. Here is a snapshot:

[image]

I still have a problem when I run the app with the right button selected, the selectionView appears outside of the containerView (it should appear on the right side of the Expensive text):

[image]

This is the code inside `viewDidLoad` when I check which button should be selected:

```
if type == .Income {
    self.selectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "28BB9D")
    self.selectionView.center = self.incomeButton.center
} else {
    self.selectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "E5344A")
}

UPDATE 2:
```

Current constraints for selectionView:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Objective**:

Create **programmatically** a `selectionView` to switch throught two `UIButton` as a child.

To explain better the situation I've added (to start) the `selectionView` to `expensiveButton` (the button where you have the issue..)

There are some corrections you could be do in your project to see it working well.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var incomeButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var expensiveButton: UIButton!
    var selectionView : UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        selectionView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 19))
        selectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        selectionView.tag = 666
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.expensiveButton.addSubview(selectionView)
        self.selectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.selectionView.center = CGPointMake(self.expensiveButton.bounds.midX, self.expensiveButton.bounds.midY)
    }
    @IBAction func incomeDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let _ = sender.viewWithTag(666) {} else {
            self.incomeButton.addSubview(selectionView)
        }
        self.expensiveButton.viewWithTag(666)?.removeFromSuperview()
        self.incomeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        self.expensiveButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.grayColor(), forState: .Normal)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
            self.selectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            self.selectionView.center = CGPointMake(self.incomeButton.bounds.midX, self.incomeButton.bounds.midY)
        }
    }
    @IBAction func expensiveDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let _ = sender.viewWithTag(666) {} else {
            self.expensiveButton.addSubview(selectionView)
        }
        self.incomeButton.viewWithTag(666)?.removeFromSuperview()
        self.expensiveButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        self.incomeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.grayColor(), forState: .Normal)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
            self.selectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            self.selectionView.center = CGPointMake(self.expensiveButton.bounds.midX, self.expensiveButton.bounds.midY)
        }
    }
}
```

**Some explaination**:

First of all in your project you don't report a global reference to `selectView` but I think you simply forgot to write it in your question.

So, a good thing is to set a tag to your selectionView, like an id number to can identify it between subviews of his future parent view (in your case it will be a `UIButton`)

As you can see I've added the `viewDidAppear` method, why? Because when you are in `viewDidLoad` your button are not completly ready, so you have a wrong center, the right place to have this value is `viewDidAppear` when your view is finally painted.

Now let's speaking about `selectionView`: it's a view, so you can add it to `incomeButton` but if you already have added it in the other button you must remove it from expensiveButton simply with this line:

```
self.expensiveButton.viewWithTag(666)?.removeFromSuperview()
```

Finally the center point: remember you are in autolayout so a good way to find it could be by using bounds:

```
self.selectionView.center = CGPointMake(self.expensiveButton.bounds.midX, self.expensiveButton.bounds.midY)
```

This is my project structure , I see you working on it:

[image]

**Update**:

After I've seen your updates (you started with a `selectionView` created programmatically) some comments and answer about your issue, I've a suspicious you want to realize a custom `UISegmentedControl`. I think using `UIStackView` to realize a little control like it it's not a good idea, you can find many project around `UISegmentedControl` that subclass `UIControl` like for example [BetterSegmentedControl](https://github.com/gmarm/BetterSegmentedControl):

**A code example**:

```
let control = BetterSegmentedControl(
    frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 100.0, width: view.bounds.width, height: 44.0),
    titles: ["One", "Two", "Three"],
    index: 1,
    backgroundColor: UIColor(red:0.11, green:0.12, blue:0.13, alpha:1.00),
    titleColor: .whiteColor(),
    indicatorViewBackgroundColor: UIColor(red:0.55, green:0.26, blue:0.86, alpha:1.00),
    selectedTitleColor: .blackColor())
control.titleFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 14.0)!
control.selectedTitleFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 14.0)!
control.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.controlValueChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
view.addSubview(control)
```

**A picture**:

[image]

Comment: If you want you can download this project here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=63536169362592196504

Comment: I have done this, because I want to animate the sliding (selectionView) from one button to another

Comment: As you can see, segmentedControl is better to achieve what do you want. In my answer I've used this custom library in past, it have a nice effects during slide. However you can try to develop your custom object, but not with stackView..

Comment: Yep, I think I am gonna go with this. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you too Kobe, I'm glad to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The key issue here is coordinate systems. You are adding the selectionView as a subview of one button or the other, but since it's moving between both, it really should be a subview of some ancestor view of both buttons.

When you are changing the selectionView center, it's animating its position *relative to its superview*, which in your current code is either the left button or the right button. Animating from left to right works, because the right button's center is some coordinate with a greater x value than the selectionView has within the left button's coordinate space.  But when you start with the selectionView inside the right button's coordinate space, the left button's center *relative to its own superview* is probably very close to the selectionView's center *relative to the right button's coordinate space*. So there isn't any real movement.

This might be easier to visualize if you think of it this way:  In order to move to where the left button is from within the right button's coordinate space, the selectionView's center x would need to be a negative number, because it would need to be left of the right button's leading edge. However, the left button's center relative to its own superview has a positive x value. So setting the selectionView's center to the left button's center will never make it move left if it's inside the right button's coordinate space.

By adding the selection view to the same superview that the two buttons are in, you can use the center coordinates in the animation successfully, because all three views (2 buttons and selectionView) will be in the same coordinate space.

If the 2 buttons are in a stack view, this could get a little messier, because you don't want to manually animate something that is being arranged by a stack view.  The solution in this case would be to wrap the stack view inside a plain UIView, and add the selectionView in front of the stack view, as a child of that same plain UIView.

As long as the stack view frame matches the bounds of the containing UIView, it will still work just fine to animated the selectionView's center between the left button center and the right button center.

### TLDR;

Use the following view hierarchy and your code will work:

```
containerView
      |____ selectionView
      |____ stackView
                |_______ leftButton
                |_______ rightButton
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but I still have issues. I have updated my questions with what I did.

Comment: @Kobe  In your update, I see the code to move the selectionView center to match the income button center if income button is selected, but I don't see code to move the center of the selectedView to the center of the expensive button in the `else` case.  Also, the selectedView in your screenshot looks like its center is equal to the expensive button's _origin_ instead of its center

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.
I did following view and constraint arrangement:

[image]

Selection view has following constraints:

[image]

Out of the 4 constraints, first constraint (Align Centre X to Stack View) is outlated to view controller.
Total Outlets are as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!
@IBOutlet weak var selectionView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var selectionviewCenterCon: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var expensiveBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var incomeBtn: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.selectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.selectionviewCenterCon.constant = -stackView.frame.size.width / 4
}

@IBAction func expensiveBtnClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.selectionviewCenterCon.constant = -stackView.frame.size.width / 4
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
        self.selectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

@IBAction func incomeBtnClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.selectionviewCenterCon.constant = stackView.frame.size.width / 4
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
        self.selectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

This code gives the output as:

[image]

[image]

Comment: My only issue is that selectionView always starts in the middle. As is setup in Storyboards.

Comment: u'r adding selection view on one of the buttons, instead add it on view. Also it needs constraints as u'r adding selection view programatically. So it's better to add selection view in xib.

Comment: That is what I did. Is not created programmatically anymore. Selection view is added to the view container that holds the stack view.

Comment: may b u'r missing constraints to container/selection/stack. coz it shouldn't happen if u added correct constraints. compare u'r constraints with mine or show u'r constraints in question!

Comment: I have updated the question with my constraints for selection view